# generate uniqe regestration code in php

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, unique-key

hello guys i need your help please

iam creating a form which store data into mysql database and every thing is good tell now.

i need to generate a code for each member fill in the form this code i need it to be like ( SUD001 ) i want it to be unique and auto increasing one i means first one fill in the form get code of (SUD001) second one gets (SUD002) thread (SUD003) and so on.

what i need is a way to do that and then insert that code into mysql database, i got no problem in inserting it into the data base but i need a function or a way to generat it.

the way that i found now is to do it like that

```
<?php

$id_num = "SUD";
  for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
  $id_num .= rand (0, 5);
  }
  echo $id_num;
  ?>
```

but this generates random number and iam not sure even it is unique or not any one

can help me please

Comment: please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345419/generating-unique-order-number/22345554#22345554

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum, please use proper punctuation and capitalization in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
 $id = uniqid('SUD');
```

Comment: That'd be quite lengthy for a user to enter somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

Steps:

- Create a field with a UNIQUE constraint in the designated MySQL table.
- Write a function 'generateCode' to generate a (long enough) code. *
- Write a function that gets that code and **tries to** enter it in the database.
- Fetch an eventual *unique constraint violation* and repeat the process from step 2 until it succeeds.

*) Be sure to use a code long enough to support your application for the coming years. 6 digits or a combination of alpha's and digits would most likely be enough.

Comment: this is not what i actually looking for :S